# SD of returns to calculate sharpe ratio

Tags: standard-deviation

So I have created some trading strategies and want to calculate the sharpe ratio which requires the Std Dev of returns. Do I calculate the Std Dev of the entire sample returns regardless or do I use the Std Dev of returns from the days the strategy enters and exits the market? I.e. if my strategy only generates 3 transactions in a year then calculating the Std dev of the 2 returns for that year may be relatively small making the sharpe ratio appear larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a little off-topic here, but I will briefly answer.

The answer to the question varies based on different points of views. Both views are required.

From a strategy performance perspective mean and stddev of returns only from traded days are relevant, since you would like to somehow rank the strategies from a risk/reward perspective. Why? Because at a certain point in time if two strategies signal an entry you would like to know which one two choose from. And at this point you possess the knowledge that the signal is triggered, therefore the fact that this strategy generates rare signals is irrelevant. If you had included the blank days, you wouldn't have chosen this strategy to trade which would have been the wrong thing to do.

On the other hand you also would like to somehow understand how your entire pool of strategies are doing. Clearly not only we want winning strategies we also want strategies that generate many trading opportunities. Moreover by including all 251 trading days in the same calculation gives you the required elements to estimate the overall performance of your entire system using mean variance portfolio optimization technique without actually running the system.

As you can see both views are required.